# No directory gets listed when connected to FTP-Server in PHP

Tags: php, php-5.3

On my webpage, I try to connect to a FTP-Server and download files from it using PHP. The connection works as expected, but when I try to change directory using `ftp_chdir()` it tells me that the directory wasn't found.

When I checked the files using `ftp_nlist()` I found, that neither directories nor files were shown.

```
$ftp_server = "server"; 
$conn_id = ftp_connect ($ftp_server) 
        or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "user", "pass"); 
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) 
        die("FTP Connection Failed"); 

$today = date("d.m.Y");

ftp_sync ($today);

ftp_close($conn_id);


function ftp_sync ($dir) { 

    global $conn_id; 

    if ($dir != ".") { 
        if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $dir) == false) { 
            echo ("Change Dir Failed: $dir<BR>\r\n"); 
            return; 
        } 
        if (!(is_dir($dir))) 
            mkdir($dir); 
        chdir ($dir); 
    } 

    $path = 'path/to/storedirectory';

    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); 
    foreach ($contents as $file) { 

        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') 
            continue; 

        if (@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $file)) { 
            ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
            ftp_sync ($file); 
        } 
        else{ 
            $local_file = $path.$file;
            ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $file, FTP_BINARY); 
        }
    } 

    ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
    chdir (".."); 

}
```

Does it have something to do with the PHP-Version, as this code executes successfully on my local webserver, but not on my webspace running with version 5.3.30, or is it some other mistake I'm making?

Comment: You might need to use passive mode from the hosted server. Try [ftp_pasv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php).

Comment: ``ftp_chdir`` still fails